# Problema com concatenação de variável

Tags: php, foreach

Tenho um variável em um `foreach` que pega a id do registro:

```
$id_inscrito = $this->session->userdata('last_id');
```

Eu quero armazenar essa variável em uma outra:

```
$ids_ = $id_inscrito.'|'.$id_inscrito;
```

Que me dê o resultado no formato `id1|id2|id3`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Use o operador `.=` para concatenar strings.

Comment: Como o `for each` vai variar? O que muda de um elemento para o outro? De onde vem a fonte de dados dele?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione o código onde está o foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do seu `foreach`, colete num array, todas as IDs, e na saída do `foreach` execute a função `implode()` do PHP para transformar em uma string com intercalações do separador que precisa:

```
$ids = array();

foreach(????) {
    $ids[] = $this->session->userdata('last_id');
}
echo implode('|', $ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma lida na função [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) do PHP.

Se na variável `$this->session->userdata('last_id')` retorna uma array com os ids que você quer, basta fazer:

```
$ids = implode('|', $this->session->userdata('last_id'));
```

E quando der um echo na variável `ids` vai retornar exatamente o que você queria. Espero ter ajudado! ;)

Comment: Não parece ser o caso de retornar um *array*, pelo menos seria estranho um método assim retornar isto.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode concatenar a string como o @rray colocou nos comentários:

```
$ids_ .= $id_inscrito .'|';
```

Lembrando que você deve inicializar a variável `$ids_` antes do loop. Outro ponto a ser considerado é que o último id sempre será seguido de um caracter `|`. Uma solução mais completa seria assim:

```
$ids_ = '';
foreach (...) {
    // codigo

    // se o $ids_ não estiver vazio adiciona '|' antes do próximo id
    $ids_ .= ($ids_ == '') ? $id_inscrito : '|' . $id_inscrito ;
}
```

---

Outra forma possível é utilizando arrays, como o @HaroldoTorres colocou em sua resposta:

```
$ids_ = array();
foreach (...) {
    // codigo

    $ids_[] = $id_inscrito;
}
$ids_ = implode('|', $ids_);
```

Comment: Não parece estranho que esse $id_inscrito` não varie? Eu acho que a pergunta não está bem feita e as respostas estão especulando soluções. Pode até ser que acertem mas sem o AP confirmar este é um código esquisito. Vai ficar algo assim: `1|1|1|1|1`. Não parece provável que ele queira isto.

Comment: @bigown O AP disse que executa esta linha dentro do `foreach`: `$id_inscrito = $this->session->userdata('last_id');`. Então imagino que o `$id_inscrito` varie sim. Ele não colocou nada informando que tem um problema com a variável. O problema no código dele é que a variável `$ids_` está sendo sobrescrevida a cada repetição.

Comment: Você pode ter razão, eu só não tenho certeza.

Comment: na base do achômetro, acho que last_id provem de uma inserção no banco de dados.. deve ter um loop inserindo novos registros no banco e no mesmo loop está aproveitando para pegar os ids e montá-los numa única string.